# TSQL WHERE Clause based on Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a large query that I am using to pull data for a report based on a filter form a user fills out. They can choose things such as location(s), department(s) as well as supervisors.

What I am currently doing is if they select `All` as the option instead of choosing a specific location, I have a temp table of all the locations that I do a `WHERE IN()` clause on.

I am trying to do something similar for my supervisor search options. A user doesn't have to select a supervisor to search by and in that case, I need it to ignore that `AND` part of the `WHERE` clause.

The last line in the code below `AND b.MgrQID IN (SELECT DISTINCT QID FROM @sourceLeaderEmps)` needs to be ignored if the temp table @sourceLeaderEmps contains no records.

Is there an easy way to go about doing this?

```
WHERE  B.[ArchibusLocationName] IN (SELECT location
                                        FROM   @tmLocations)
           AND C.[ArchibusLocationName] IN (SELECT location
                                            FROM   @subLocations)
           AND B.[DepartmentDesc] IN (SELECT department
                                      FROM   @tmDepartments)
           AND C.[DepartmentDesc] IN (SELECT department
                                      FROM   @subDepartments)
           AND DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', CAST (CONVERT (DATETIME, A.[escalationCreated], 121) AS INT)) >= @startDate
           AND DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', CAST (CONVERT (DATETIME, A.[escalationCreated], 121) AS INT)) <= @endDate
           AND a.[PREVENTABLE] IN (SELECT PREVENTABLE
                                   FROM   @preventable)
           AND b.MgrQID IN (SELECT DISTINCT QID FROM @sourceLeaderEmps)
```

Comment: You have a couple of performance issues here. First is that you have to cast every single row into a datetime then decide if you want it. The second issue is that you have your column in a function. Both of these render your query nonSARGable. Storing data in the proper datatype is a good start but you also need to get the column outside the datediff function.

Comment: Thanks for the information @SeanLange - I wish I knew more about this stuff in order to make use of your feedback as I'm sure it would help greatly. The reason I have the datediff function there is because I am using a chart plugin that allows me to narrow down the results by dragging over a range of dates I want to see closer. This plugin passes the unix timestamps to the SP in which I have to look up the dates that fall in between that range passed.

Comment: Another performance concern is all the table variables. If there are lots of rows those can get horribly slow due to the lack of statistics and indexes. I am guessing that your startdate and enddate variables are ints that contain Unix style date values?

Comment: The actual data in the table for start and end date are stored in the date time format. The unix time stamp is created in the UI based on the data you have selected. It passes it to the SP, determines the actual time frame and then looks at the data that meets that criteria.

Comment: We don't store datetime in a format. That is why I asked about the datatype. Are they int? You only provided a portion of your code. Providing all your code would make this a lot easier. That being said I think what you are trying to do here is a search type of query. Take a look at this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: The datatype that the date is stored in is `datetime`. I will take a look at the link provided and see what I can gather from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a "count" variable.

```
declare @sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT int
```

Hydrate it

```
select @sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT = count(*) from @sourceLeaderEmps
```

Now do a OR clause

```
Where
/* other stuff */
and
((   ( @sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT = 0) OR  (/* your in or exists clause here */  )   ))
```

Something like this:

```
    declare @sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT int
    select @sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT = count(*) from @sourceLeaderEmps



WHERE  B.[ArchibusLocationName] IN (SELECT location
                                        FROM   @tmLocations)
           AND C.[ArchibusLocationName] IN (SELECT location
                                            FROM   @subLocations)
           AND B.[DepartmentDesc] IN (SELECT department
                                      FROM   @tmDepartments)
           AND C.[DepartmentDesc] IN (SELECT department
                                      FROM   @subDepartments)
           AND DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', CAST (CONVERT (DATETIME, A.[escalationCreated], 121) AS INT)) >= @startDate
           AND DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', CAST (CONVERT (DATETIME, A.[escalationCreated], 121) AS INT)) <= @endDate
           AND a.[PREVENTABLE] IN (SELECT PREVENTABLE
                                   FROM   @preventable)
           AND ((  (@sourceLeaderEmpsCOUNT=0) OR (b.MgrQID IN (SELECT DISTINCT QID FROM @sourceLeaderEmps) ) ))
```

Comment: While this looks promising, I gave it a try but any time I have the modified `AND` statement in there, I get zero results when I don't have any `@sourceLeaderEmps`.

Comment: The parentheses matter alot.  It has always worked for me (the @Count=0 OR (Something Else)) trick ......  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/104566/

Comment: Weird, okay I will keep playing around with the code and try determine where the issue is. Thanks

Comment: get rid of all the other clauses ... (temporarily) and work with just the @Count or IN clause ........ then after you see it work.... build up from there.....would be my advice.